# nginx reverse proxy -> double header

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, hsts

I've looking at this problem for a really long time, now it's time to ask for help:

No matter what I tried, every option, that I add to the server header gets passed two times, giving me bad results on SSL labs and especially on mozillas oberservatory.

So, here's my config (from a subdirectory in nginx):

```
server {
 listen 80 default_server;
 server_name colony47.de www.colony47.de;
 rewrite ^ https://colony47.de$request_uri permanent;

 root /var/www;

 location ^~ /.well-known/acme-challenge {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:81;
        proxy_redirect off;
 }

 location / {
         # Enforce HTTPS
         #return 301 https://$server_addr$request_uri;
         # Use this if you always want to redirect to the DynDNS address (no local access).
         return 301 https://colony47.de$request_uri;
        }
 }

server {
 listen 443 ssl http2;
 server_name colony47.de www.colony47.de;

 root /var/www;

 ssl on;

 # Certificates used
 ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/colony47.de/fullchain.pem;
 ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/colony47.de/privkey.pem;

 ssl_protocols TLSv1.2;

 # These are the recommended cipher suites from: https://wiki.mozilla.org/Security/Server_Side_TLS
 ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-DSS$

 # Diffie-Hellman parameter for DHE ciphersuites, recommended 2048 bits
 ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/ssl/dhparams.pem;

# ssl_ecdh_curve secp384r1;
 ssl_ecdh_curve prime256v1;
 ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

 # OCSP Stapling
 # fetch OCSP records from URL in ssl_certificate and cache them
 ssl_stapling on;
 ssl_stapling_verify on;
 ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/colony47.de/fullchain.pem;

 # SSL session handling
 ssl_session_timeout 24h;
 ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:50m;
 ssl_session_tickets off;

 add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=15768001; includeSubDomains; preload";

 add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
 add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
 add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
 add_header X-Robots-Tag none;
 add_header X-Download-Options noopen;
 add_header X-Permitted-Cross-Domain-Policies none;
```

Everything added to the header is doubled when tested, uncommenting disables it completly.

Any advise, how to pass every option only one time and help to solve this problem would help a lot!

Thanks in advance!